# function not working : Outcome = missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

sorry for opening the 1.000.001st topic on "missing 1 required positional argument" but I am too new to coding. Can't really read the code and make sense out of them. so, I hope I can get some help before I go crazy.

```
class DataScientist():

    workers = []
    langs = []
    def __init__(self):
       self.lang = []
       self.depr =''
    def add_lang(self, new_lang ) :
       self.lang.append(new_lang )
```

and every time I try to add an object like this:

```
mike = DataScientist

mike.add_lang("R")
```

I get " add_lang(): missing 1 required positional argument: new_lang"

I am taking online classes and writing the same codes as I see them, somehow mine doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the parantheses when instantiating your object. Instead you're assigning the class itself. `DataScientist`-> `DataScientist()`. Tha actual argument missing in your function is `self` but it thinks you're passing `'R'` as `self`, and missing the `lang` arg

Comment: use `mike = DataScientist()` because `add_lang` is an class instance method

Answer (score 1):

In def add_lang(self, new_lang ) :

```
self.lang.append(new_lang )
```

You need to change 'lang' to list name 'langs'